# If-Else with 4 Conditions to make a visual occurance graph

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested-if

So I'm trying to create a visual representation of the occurrence of an event on a sheet using the data from another sheet for a 10-year span. I'm taking the data from 3 columns from another sheet. The columns contain info for the date (month/year), signal #, and action #. On the sheet, where I'm graphing, I'm putting an 'X, if the event occurs and blank space if nothing happens. The occurrence sheet looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQ1Tc.png). Does anyone know how to make a nested 4 condition if-else statement for this? There aren't a lot of examples of 4 condition statements online.

Answer (score 0):

you can use AND and OR inside an IF formula.
For example to have three conditions to be met:
IF(AND(Date = "this date";signal# = 1;action # = 2);"X";" ")